Which K-Map is the correct one?
Which of the K-Map is correct and the reason behind it ?

Both appear to be correct.

Both generate correct expressions but if by "correct" you mean the one which generates the most simplified sum of products: the second one.
The group of 4 will eliminate two inputs. The group of two eliminates only one.
